# One-side data synchronization between two apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, architecture, database-schema

There are 2 applications, let's say old and new. Both applications have a User entity, each user has many posts.

Initially data in the new app is a full copy of the old one. But then it will be modified in both places independently.

The old application's code can't be modified, the new app must contain data changes from both apps. If there are changes in both apps for one user then they should be merged (automatically or with user interaction).

In real apps, it's much more associations and schema is slightly different.

What's the best approach for this?

Comment: Hi, Is it more of managing the source code or data in the databases? This part bit confusing can you please explain... "The old application's code can't be modified, the new must contain data changes from both apps. If there are changes in both apps for one user then they should be merged (automatically or with user interaction)."

Comment: Code or schema in the old app can't be modified in order to add anything. Code in new app can be changed to manage data updates.

Answer (score 0):

You have old App and its entity. You will be copying from the old app and will be making the modification based on change requests and build them as new app. Now, you want to maintain only new app and its entity for any new changes or enhancements.

### Please follow the following steps,

- Copy both code (if you wish otherwise write from scratch) and entity from old app

### If there is a change in Business Workflow

- Write an intermediate components which transforms/parse old data into new data schema
- New app will always speak to the new DAL (new entity) layer
- The old app will be passed through the intermediate (wrapper class) to transform/parse the old entity into new one

### If no changes in Business flow but only schema

- Implement any ETL, which suits your need

### NOTE:

- Identify the components or entities, which will be modified, if changes are limited to certain components

Hope this will help you to get the insights and apply for your problem.

Thanks